# Send notification to smartphone when a new child is added in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Even if I have the feeling that this question has already been answered, something is missing in my reflexion.

If I want, when a new child is added in my Firebase Realtime Database, to send a notification to some users smartphones (it could be iOS or Android), I have to setup a NodeJS server and install Cloud Messaging to monitor the database and send the order to Notifications in Firebase to send the notifications.

Am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest looking into Cloud Functions for Firebase, so you don't need your own server.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: I would second Cloud Functions. Setting up your own server is way too much work when Firebase has a built in "functions" service. All you will need to do is create a call when the child node is written to that then uses "firebase admin" to send a message to the devices you choose. Let me know if you want an example of this because I could easily copy over one of my functions for you.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your answer. This is what I've been looking yesterday but from what I saw, the only examples are in .js so how can I make this work with either iOS or Android?

Comment: @Drei yes, if you have an example for Android, I'm of course interesting :)

Comment: Alright, I got it now!
What wasn't clear for me is that you run locally your nodeJS to write functions and then upload them to Firebase. As it was written anywhere I read, I understood it like you needed a server to deal with this. I'll try to write some functions now :)
Thanks guys!